# compilation error in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, compile

I'm new to arduino. I had found an interesting project to work on with, but unfortunately I'm held up at compilation error. I tried finding answers to this problem but not able to understand.

Here is my code:

```
    // Include Libraries
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Adafruit_TCS34725.h>

// Initialize Sensors
Adafruit_TCS34725 tcs = Adafruit_TCS34725(TCS34725_INTEGRATIONTIME_50MS, TCS34725_GAIN_4X);
Servo myservoRed;
Servo myservoGreen;
Servo myservoBlue;


int posRed = 0;   
int posGreen = 0;
int posBlue = 0; 


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Color View Test!");

  if (tcs.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Found sensor");
  } else {
    Serial.println("No TCS34725 found ... check your connections");
    while (1); // halt!
  }

  //Attach servos to ouput pins
  myservoRed.attach(9);   
  myservoGreen.attach(6);
  myservoBlue.attach(3);

  // Initialize Fan pin
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);

}


void loop() {
  uint16_t clear, red, green, blue;
  tcs.setInterrupt(false);      
  delay(60);  // takes 50ms to read 
  tcs.getRawData(&red, &green, &blue, &clear);
  tcs.setInterrupt(true);  
  Serial.print("C:\t"); Serial.print(clear);
  Serial.print("\tR:\t"); Serial.print(red);
  Serial.print("\tG:\t"); Serial.print(green);
  Serial.print("\tB:\t"); Serial.print(blue);

  // Map color to motor position
  posRed = map(red,100,10000,10,80);
  Serial.print("\tRedPos:\t"); Serial.print(posRed);
  posGreen = map(green,100,10000,10,80);
  Serial.print("\tGreenPos:\t"); Serial.print(posGreen);
  posBlue = map(blue,100,10000,10,80);
  Serial.print("\tBluePos:\t"); Serial.print(posBlue);
  Serial.println();

  // Write position to motor
  myservoRed.write(posRed);
  delay(100); 
  myservoGreen.write(posGreen); 
  delay(100); 
  myservoBlue.write(posBlue); 
  delay(100);          


}
```

Here is the Wire.h:

```
/*
 * TwoWire.h - TWI/I2C library for Linux Userspace
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Parav https://github.com/meanbot.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 */

#ifndef TwoWire_h
#define TwoWire_h

#include "Stream.h"
#include "variant.h"

#define BUFFER_LENGTH 32
#define I2C2 0x4819c000
#define I2C1 0x00000000
#define WIRE_INTERFACES_COUNT 1

class TwoWire : public Stream {
public:
    TwoWire(void(*begin_cb)(void));
    void begin();
    void begin(uint8_t);
    void begin(int);
    void beginTransmission(uint8_t);
    void beginTransmission(int);
    uint8_t endTransmission(void);
    uint8_t endTransmission(uint8_t);
    uint8_t requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t);
    uint8_t requestFrom(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t);
    uint8_t requestFrom(int, int);
    uint8_t requestFrom(int, int, int);
    virtual size_t write(uint8_t);
    virtual size_t write(const uint8_t *, size_t);
    virtual int available(void);
    virtual int read(void);
    virtual int peek(void);
    virtual void flush(void);
    void onReceive(void(*)(int));
    void onRequest(void(*)(void));

    inline size_t write(unsigned long n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
    inline size_t write(long n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
    inline size_t write(unsigned int n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
    inline size_t write(int n) { return write((uint8_t)n); }
    using Print::write;

    void onService(void);

private:
    // RX Buffer
    uint8_t rxBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    uint8_t rxBufferIndex;
    uint8_t rxBufferLength;

    // TX Buffer
    uint8_t txAddress;
    uint8_t txBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    uint8_t txBufferLength;

    // Service buffer
    uint8_t srvBuffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    uint8_t srvBufferIndex;
    uint8_t srvBufferLength;

    // Callback user functions
    void (*onRequestCallback)(void);
    void (*onReceiveCallback)(int);

    // Called before initialization
    void (*onBeginCallback)(void);

    // Timeouts (
    static const uint32_t RECV_TIMEOUT = 100000;
    static const uint32_t XMIT_TIMEOUT = 100000;

    uint8_t adapter_nr;
    int i2c_fd;
    int i2c_transfer;
};

#if WIRE_INTERFACES_COUNT > 0
extern TwoWire Wire;
#endif
#if WIRE_INTERFACES_COUNT > 1
extern TwoWire Wire1;
#endif

#endif
```

Here is Wire.cpp:

```
/*
 * TwoWire.h - TWI/I2C library for Linux Userspace
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Parav https://github.com/meanbot.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 */

extern "C" {
#include <string.h>
#include <i2c.h>
}

#include "Wire.h"

#include <Mux.h>
#include <trace.h>
#define MY_TRACE_PREFIX "Wire"

TwoWire::TwoWire(void(*_beginCb)(void)) : rxBufferIndex(0), rxBufferLength(0),
                      txAddress(0), txBufferLength(0),
                      srvBufferIndex(0), srvBufferLength(0),
                      onBeginCallback(_beginCb),
                      adapter_nr(-1), i2c_fd(-1),
                      i2c_transfer(0)
{
    // Empty
}

void TwoWire::begin(void)
{
    muxSelectI2c(0);
    if (onBeginCallback)
        onBeginCallback();
    if ((adapter_nr = i2c_getadapter(I2C2)) < 0) {
        return;
    }
    if ((i2c_fd = i2c_openadapter(adapter_nr)) < 0) {
        return;
    }

}

void TwoWire::begin(uint8_t address)
{
    if (onBeginCallback)
        onBeginCallback();
}

void TwoWire::begin(int address)
{
    begin((uint8_t) address);
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t address, uint8_t quantity, uint8_t sendStop)
{
    if (quantity > BUFFER_LENGTH)
        quantity = BUFFER_LENGTH;

    /* Set slave address via ioctl  */
    i2c_setslave(i2c_fd, address);

    if(i2c_transfer) {
    /* Need to perform a combined read/write operation
     */
        i2c_transfer = 0;
        if (sendStop == false)
            return 0;
        i2c_add_to_buf(address, 1, rxBuffer, quantity);
        if (!i2c_readwrite(i2c_fd)) {
            rxBufferIndex = 0;
            rxBufferLength = quantity;
            i2c_transfer = 0;
            return quantity;
        } else
            return 0;
    }
    if (i2c_readbytes(i2c_fd, rxBuffer, quantity) < 0)
        return 0;
    // set rx buffer iterator vars
    rxBufferIndex = 0;
    rxBufferLength = quantity;

    return quantity;
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(uint8_t address, uint8_t quantity)
{
    return requestFrom((uint8_t) address, (uint8_t) quantity, (uint8_t) true);
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(int address, int quantity)
{
    return requestFrom((uint8_t) address, (uint8_t) quantity, (uint8_t) true);
}

uint8_t TwoWire::requestFrom(int address, int quantity, int sendStop)
{
    return requestFrom((uint8_t) address, (uint8_t) quantity, (uint8_t) sendStop);
}

void TwoWire::beginTransmission(uint8_t address)
{
    if (i2c_fd < 0 || adapter_nr < 0)
        return;
    /* set slave address via ioctl in case we need to perform terminating
     * write operation
     */
    i2c_setslave(i2c_fd, address);
    // save address of target and empty buffer
    txAddress = address;
    txBufferLength = 0;
}

void TwoWire::beginTransmission(int address)
{
    beginTransmission((uint8_t) address);
}

//
//  Originally, 'endTransmission' was an f(void) function.
//  It has been modified to take one parameter indicating
//  whether or not a STOP should be performed on the bus.
//  Calling endTransmission(false) allows a sketch to
//  perform a repeated start.
//
//  WARNING: Nothing in the library keeps track of whether
//  the bus tenure has been properly ended with a STOP. It
//  is very possible to leave the bus in a hung state if
//  no call to endTransmission(true) is made. Some I2C
//  devices will behave oddly if they do not see a STOP.
//
uint8_t TwoWire::endTransmission(uint8_t sendStop)
{
    int err;
    if (sendStop == true) {

        // transmit buffer (blocking)
        if (txBufferLength > 1)
            err = i2c_writebytes(i2c_fd, txBuffer, txBufferLength);
        else if (txBufferLength == 1)
            err = i2c_writebyte(i2c_fd, *txBuffer);
        else
        /* FIXME: A zero byte transmit is typically used to check for an
         * ACK from the slave device. I'm not sure if this is the
         * correct way to do this.
         */
            err = i2c_readbyte(i2c_fd);
        // empty buffer
        txBufferLength = 0;
        if (err < 0)
            return 2;
        return 0;
    } else {
    /* sendStop = false
     * pretend we have held the bus while
     * actually waiting for the next operation
     */
        i2c_add_to_buf(txAddress, 0, txBuffer, txBufferLength);
        i2c_transfer = 1;
        return 0;
    }
}

//  This provides backwards compatibility with the original
//  definition, and expected behaviour, of endTransmission
//
uint8_t TwoWire::endTransmission(void)
{
    return endTransmission(true);
}

size_t TwoWire::write(uint8_t data)
{
    if (txBufferLength >= BUFFER_LENGTH)
        return 0;
    txBuffer[txBufferLength++] = data;
    return 1;
}

size_t TwoWire::write(const uint8_t *data, size_t quantity)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < quantity; ++i) {
        if (txBufferLength >= BUFFER_LENGTH)
            return i;
        txBuffer[txBufferLength++] = data[i];
    }
    return quantity;
}

int TwoWire::available(void)
{
    return rxBufferLength - rxBufferIndex;
}

int TwoWire::read(void)
{
    if (rxBufferIndex < rxBufferLength)
        return rxBuffer[rxBufferIndex++];
    return -1;
}

int TwoWire::peek(void)
{
    if (rxBufferIndex < rxBufferLength)
        return rxBuffer[rxBufferIndex];
    return -1;
}

void TwoWire::flush(void)
{
    // Do nothing, use endTransmission(..) to force
    // data transfer.
}

void TwoWire::onReceive(void(*function)(int))
{
    onReceiveCallback = function;
}

void TwoWire::onRequest(void(*function)(void)) {
    onRequestCallback = function;
}

void TwoWire::onService(void)
{
}

#if WIRE_INTERFACES_COUNT > 0
static void Wire_Init(void)
{
}

TwoWire Wire = TwoWire(Wire_Init);

void WIRE_ISR_HANDLER(void) {
    Wire.onService();
}
#endif

#if WIRE_INTERFACES_COUNT > 1
static void Wire1_Init(void)
{
    if ((adapter_nr = i2c_getadapter(I2C1)) < 0) {
        return;
    }
    if ((i2c_fd = i2c_openadapter) < 0) {
        return;
    }
}

TwoWire Wire1 = TwoWire(Wire1_Init);

void WIRE1_ISR_HANDLER(void) {
    Wire1.onService();
}
#endif
```

Here is the error message i got:

```
libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `WIRE_ISR_HANDLER()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:186: multiple definition of `TwoWire::write(unsigned char)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:186: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:194: multiple definition of `TwoWire::write(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:194: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::requestFrom(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:204: multiple definition of `TwoWire::available()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:204: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::read()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:209: multiple definition of `TwoWire::read()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:209: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::peek()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:216: multiple definition of `TwoWire::peek()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:216: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::flush()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:223: multiple definition of `TwoWire::flush()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:223: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::TwoWire(void (*)())':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:32: multiple definition of `TwoWire::TwoWire(void (*)())'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:32: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::TwoWire(void (*)())':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:32: multiple definition of `TwoWire::TwoWire(void (*)())'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:32: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::begin()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:43: multiple definition of `TwoWire::begin()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:43: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::begin(unsigned char)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:57: multiple definition of `TwoWire::begin(unsigned char)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:57: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::begin(int)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:63: multiple definition of `TwoWire::begin(int)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:63: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::requestFrom(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:68: multiple definition of `TwoWire::requestFrom(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:68: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::requestFrom(unsigned char, unsigned char)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:100: multiple definition of `TwoWire::requestFrom(unsigned char, unsigned char)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:100: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:105: multiple definition of `TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:105: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int, int)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:110: multiple definition of `TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int, int)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:110: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::beginTransmission(unsigned char)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:115: multiple definition of `TwoWire::beginTransmission(unsigned char)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:115: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:128: multiple definition of `TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:128: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::endTransmission(unsigned char)':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:146: multiple definition of `TwoWire::endTransmission(unsigned char)'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:146: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::endTransmission()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:181: multiple definition of `TwoWire::endTransmission()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:181: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::onReceive(void (*)(int))':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:229: multiple definition of `TwoWire::onReceive(void (*)(int))'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:229: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::onRequest(void (*)())':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:233: multiple definition of `TwoWire::onRequest(void (*)())'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:233: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `TwoWire::onService()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:238: multiple definition of `TwoWire::onService()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:238: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `WIRE_ISR_HANDLER()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:248: multiple definition of `WIRE_ISR_HANDLER()'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:248: first defined here

libraries\Servo\Wire.cpp.o: In function `WIRE_ISR_HANDLER()':

C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Servo\src/Wire.cpp:186: multiple definition of `Wire'

libraries\Wire\Wire.cpp.o:C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\Intel\hardware\i686\1.6.7+1.0\libraries\Wire\src/Wire.cpp:186: first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

Comment: Looks like the Servo library has Wire source files in it for some reason. I checked my Servo library, and it doesn't have those, so not sure what's going on there, but maybe try removing Wire.cpp from Servo/src/? (keep in the file so you can put it back if necessary)

Comment: I agree with uint128_t - it looks like you have an improper installation. Somehow Wire.cpp is being compiled twice.

Comment: Thank you uint128_t. I found that the servo library had wire library files. Removed the files and things are working great.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Servo library has Wire source files in it for some reason. I checked my Servo library, and it doesn't have those, so not sure what's going on there, but maybe try removing Wire.cpp from Servo/src/? (keep in the file so you can put it back if necessary)

**credits to uint128_t**(in the comments)

Based on his suggestion i removed the 
*wire* library files present in servo library folder and things worked just fine.